# Возможности word2vec. Инструменты для поиска фраз

Tags: python, семантика

Какие существуют библиотеки, модели для таких задач как:

Определение "логичности" словосочетаний (металлический платок - не логично, красный платок - логично);
Составление наиболее вероятного словосочетания для какого-то слова

Т.е. грубо говоря что-то, что хранит в себе информацию о последовательности слов  и их связях между собой

Алгоритм для word2vec придумать не получилось, что в целом логично учитывая какую задачу выполняет данная сеть.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлись данные ресурсы:
https://rvb.ru/soft/catalogue/c01.html
http://www.garshin.ru/linguistics/applied/quantitative-ling-soft.html

C одной из программ удалось решить задачу